# Coolant fluid being consumed up fast (1.5 liters in just two to three days)

Tags: coolant, cooling-system, coolant-leak, coolant-reservoir

My friend owns a VW Golf Mk4 1.6 SR year 1998.
Recently he is having issues with the coolant fluid being consumed up really fast, approximately 1.5 liters in just two to three days.

The first thing that came to mind was checking for a leak.
Both when the car is turned on and turned off there is no sign of a leak, all the hoses are looking okay.

The car was even looked by a mechanic and even he does not have a clue of what could be the problem.

Is is somehow possible that this fluid evaporates somewhere, or what else could be the issue?

Comment: Is he using a 50/50 coolant/water mixture? Does the oil (on the dipstick) look ok? Has his car's engine been running in the "normal" temp range? Has he been filling up the coolant-overflow-tank?

Comment: Is there something dripping from the heater unit in the interior? Is the heater working?

Comment: "Both when the car is turned on and turned off there is no sign of a leak" When everything is cold, water won't drip out of a small hole because there is nowhere for air to get in to replace it. When everything is hot, you can't easily see a bit of steam escaping. But most likely you have a cracked cylinder head gasket and the water is getting into the cylinders and disappearing out of the tail pipe as steam. Again, the crack may be sealing itself up if you do a pressure test on a cold engine, but a mechanic *should* know about stuff like that!

Comment: Good point, @alephzero! That *should* cause white smoke to come out the tail pipe, right? How much driving has your friend done during the time the 1.5 liters has disappeared?

Comment: @Sam the mixture is 50/50, the oil is okay, the car temperature runs in the normal range, he has added more coolant/water mixture.

Comment: @Al_ Heater is working and there is nothing dipping from the unit in the interior.

Comment: @alephzero no cracks on cylinders as well.

Comment: @Sam there is no white smoke coming out of the tail pipe. When it comes to how much he has be driving it is probably around 100 to 150 km.

Comment: Does the heater smell funny in any way at the vents? Had a look at the external radiator as well?